# NVError 0x120002 when flashing system.img to Lenova IdeaPad K1

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking

So I was trying to root the Lenova Ideapad K1 tablet using [this guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1564002) and it seems I've messed up. I can only boot into APX mode now. Is there a way for me to restore this?

CMD prompt output below:

```
    Ideapad K1 Honeycomb Rooted Rom + CWM

Baased off the 14_14_120109 build [Honeycomb 3.2.1]

Make sure you have already installed the APX drivers before starting

Power off your K1 and place into APX mode (Vol+, Vol-, Power)

Press any key to continue . . .

Nvflash started
rcm version 0X20001
System Information:
   chip name: t20
   chip id: 0x20 major: 1 minor: 4
   chip sku: 0x8
   chip uid: 0x04289144423fa557
   macrovision: disabled
   hdcp: enabled
   sbk burned: true
   dk burned: true
   boot device: emmc
   operating mode: 4
   device config strap: 0
   device config fuse: 0
   sdram config strap: 0

sending file: flash.bct
- 4080/4080 bytes sent
flash.bct sent successfully
odm data: 0x300c0011
downloading bootloader -- load address: 0x108000 entry point: 0x108000
sending file: bootloader.bin
\ 1648325/1648325 bytes sent
bootloader.bin sent successfully
waiting for bootloader to initialize
bootloader downloaded successfully
setting device: 2 3
creating partition: BCT
creating partition: PT
creating partition: EBT
creating partition: GP1
creating partition: SOS
creating partition: LNX
creating partition: APP
creating partition: CAC
creating partition: MSC
creating partition: USP
creating partition: UDA
creating partition: TMP
creating partition: GPT
Formatting partition 2 BCT please wait.. done!
Formatting partition 3 PT please wait.. done!
Formatting partition 4 EBT please wait.. done!
Formatting partition 5 GP1 please wait.. done!
Formatting partition 6 SOS please wait.. done!
Formatting partition 7 LNX please wait.. done!
Formatting partition 8 APP please wait.. done!
Formatting partition 9 CAC please wait.. done!
Formatting partition 10 MSC please wait.. done!
Formatting partition 11 USP please wait.. done!
Formatting partition 12 UDA please wait.. done!
Formatting partition 13 TMP please wait.. done!
Formatting partition 14 GPT please wait.. done!
done!
sending file: bootloader.bin
\ 1648325/1648325 bytes sent
bootloader.bin sent successfully
sending file: recovery.img
\ 4550656/4550656 bytes sent
recovery.img sent successfully
sending file: boot.img
- 3209216/3209216 bytes sent
boot.img sent successfully
sending file: system.img
/ 17563648/419430400 bytes sentdata send failed NvError 0x120002
command failure: create failed (bad data)



Press any key to exit...
```